# Upgraded Postfix, Relay Is Broken Now

Tags: mysql, debian, postfix, virtualization, smtp

I upgraded from Debian 5 to Debian 6, and in doing so went from Postfix 2.5.5 to 2.7.1.  I'm using MySQL as a backend for virtual domains/mailboxes.

After the upgrade, I'm able to receive mail from outside sources, but when I try to relay outbound mail, I'm getting 554 Relay access denied.  Here's what I think are the relevant configuration parameters in my main.cf:

```
mydestination =
relayhost = # using virtuals
mynetworks = all
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    #reject_unauth_destination,
    check_relay_domains,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    permit
```

Can someone please help me to understand what might have changed in the upgrade that would cause this to break?

Comment: I hate to say it but I have been bitten by this too many times.  If you depend on a software package for production services, you should be compiling and installing it in `/opt`.  Depending on a distro's packaging (even as good as debian), eventually gets you in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `mynetworks = all` is no longer a valid setting.  Changed this to `mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8`, restarted postfix, and it's working again.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't be much helpful for you but it would be worth reading:

- [Upgrades from debian 5.0 (debian 6.0 release notes)](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#trouble)
- [Issues to be aware (debian 6.0 release notes)](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-information.en.html)